# Burritoise Vs Burrito?

Tags: word-choice, neologisms, verbing

I was [explaining something](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194665/2788) using an analogy with burritos. If I apply the same burrito analogy to other examples, am I Burritoising those examples or Burritoing them?

[image: stack exchange revision screenshot showing the word burrito changing to burritoise]

> By analogy, say you were banned from buying burritos, but you had a coupon [...]
> [...]
> Now, if you burritoise/burrito the other [...]

I'm using [-ise/-ize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ize) in the same way the act of making something pixelated is 'to pixelise'.

> cause to be or conform to or resemble

So in this case I would assume 'burritoise' would mean 'cause to conform to' my burrito analogy? I think the counterargument is that 'burrito' is already a verb.

Which is correct?

Comment: You are asking for what's the right amount of wrong, by inventing a word that's startling enough yet understable. Could you just use *burrito* the other?

Comment: Would *burritoise* becoms *burritoize* in the US?

Comment: @Yeosef, Wiktionary contains that [usage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burrito#Verb): *(slang) To wrap someone or something up like a burrito.* Which is not relevant

Comment: Burritoise sounds French like Francoise.

Comment: You can make a verb (called verbing) of anything at all, but it should be understandable at the very least.

Comment: One can't just assume that regular trends are universal rules. Many aspects of English are productive features, but one can't make up words at will: productivity is generally not absolute. And while you can experiment to your heart's content in a free country, ELU deals with standard usages. What is in the usual dictionaries: they often show non-standardness by not including non-words.

Comment: @lambie, I'm sorry you didn't find the word intuitive. I've added extra explanation to the question.

Comment: You have not told us what you mean by it. What I dislike more than anything else around here are bits and bobs like this: Now, if you burritoise/burritoing the other [...]. which do not help one to make a **cogent** comment. It only serves to send the discussion off into the ether.

Comment: @lambie the full context is in the linked question, but I've added even more explanation.

Comment: “-ize” is the best written form here. In speech, your prior references to a *burrito* will make your meaning clear.  You can also accent the word or use air quotes. For the reader without this contextual information, the hyphen helps make your meaning more apparent.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the analogy you're making? I read the relevant section in the linked answer but it goes into spells producing tokens and I stop understanding.

Comment: The title and first quote are confusing cause "Burritoise" and "Burritoing" are not the same tense. The title should be "Burritoising vs Burritoing", no?

Comment: *Burrito* is a verb in this context. Carry on.

Comment: If you have established that you are using a burrito analogy, then simply say *wrap* when you need a verb meaning "to wrap."   If you want to describe the entire process, sure, go wild with *burritofication* or whatever you want.

Comment: But then you'd have to decide whether *burritoise* rhymes with *vichyssoise* and other *cuisine bourgeoise*, or with *equipoise* and *bury-noise*, or with *tortoise* and *porpoise*.

Comment: @tchrist /bəˈɹiː.təʊaɪz/

Comment: @stevesliva did you manage to read the whole liked question? The burritoification in them.is not to do with wrapping at all.

Comment: @Pureferret - too many words about whether *someone else* can be your familiar.   Using *burrito* as a verb is just going to mean *wrap* to most people.   The *make* vs. *can make* distinction about mechanics etc seems not all that relevant.  They stuck *can* in there when they switched the subject from *you* to *you or someone else*, but it's the *someone else* that's the crux of things.

Comment: *burrito* is obviously the participle (in Italian) of *burrire*!  The question remains how to anglicize this verb; I think I'd go with *burrish* by analogy with *finish*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M-W Unabridged comes down on the side of *burritofy*:

> **-fy**, *verb suffix*
>
> **1** : make : form into
>
> **2** : invest with the attributes of : make similar to

So you're *burritofying* your other examples — refried beans and all.

Comment: One must apply the Burrito Principle 20% of the filling stains 80% of your shirt

Comment: How does this win out over M-W's [*-ize*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ize)?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Largely because _burritofication_ sounded more mellifluous than _burritoization_ to my ears, as well as being easier to parse visually.

Comment: I'd have to agree with that.